# django models that contains list of another model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to make a django model that can have a list of another model as an attribute

```
def author:
    name = charfield...
    list_of_books = ______________

def book:
    name = charfield...
```

I want an author to be able to have a list of books he has written. And I would like to know how I can add a book to the authors list of books.

I have seen foreignKey, but It seems like that it only to hold one object.

Answer (score 2):

Use a ForeignKey in the other direction. book should contain a ForeignKey to author, and, by default, author will then contain the member book_set that has a list of all books that are associated with that author.

If you intend for a book to be able to have more than one author, a ManyToManyField would be more appropriate.

To see all the books by a particular author, you'd want to use author.book_set.all()

[This page](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter10.html) contains an example of a database that uses books, authors, and publishers, where the relationship between authors and books is represented as a ManyToManyField.

Comment: So say I want to iterate and print out all of the books an author has written, how would i do that?

Comment: list_of_booKs = author.book_set.all(); for book in list_of_books: print book

Comment: This does mean that a Book can only have one Author. Perhaps a ManyToManyField would be better here?

Comment: @Ben True, though that's the way I read the problem statement as being intended. You're quite correct, though, so I'll revise my answer to include that.

Comment: @Jon great link to the Django book - I knew I'd seen a tutorial somewhere with Books and Authors!

Comment: The link is broken