# Django ORM : model with a list of items from another model

Tags: python, django, orm, django-orm

In my Django models, I have two models : one called *Site* and the other *SiteFeature*.

**Object-wise**, it is very clear how this should work : every instance of the *Site* class should have as property a list containing instances of the *SiteFeature* class, simply because the *SiteFeature* objects should only exist in relation to a *Site* object.

**Database-wise**, it is also very clear how it should work : the *SiteFeature* table should contain a not-nullable column referencing the primary key id column of the *Site* table, with a foreign key.

But in terms of Django ORM, I don't know how to code this.

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18415130/django-models-that-contains-list-of-another-model), and [this other example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31702487/django-filter-a-model-with-a-field-from-another-model), it seems the classical way to proceed works the other way round :

- The *Site* model class contains no ORM model field referencing the *SiteFeature* list.
- Instead, the *SiteFeature* ORM model class has a *ForeignKey* field referencing the *Site* class.

I see there is a way to code this out : by adding a function to the *Site* model class that searches all the related *SiteFeature*, and make this function a property (decorator *@property*):

```
@property
def site_features(self):
    return SiteFeature.objects.filter(site_id=site_id)
```

But that leaves me doubts :

The proper logic for me would also be that when I save, update or create an instance of the *Site* class, it would also automatically save / update / create the instances of *SiteFeature* that are related to it. (same thing for deleting the object, but that can be covered by the `on_delete=models.CASCADE` parameter of the ForeignKey field).
I could add my own *save_with_features* / *update_with_features* / *create_with_features* methods that cascade all but I am not sure what would happen in case of calls made automatically by Django to the standard save / update / create such as in bulk operations.

**This problem seems to basic that I suppose there is already a proper way to do it.** How would that be ?

Answer (score 1):

Eventually, I solved the problem with the `sitefeature_set` Manager.

Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward